# Very slow downloading data to app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing uwp app.

I try to download json and display data.

I send to method lan and lon variables, put it and link and download data.

Location code:

```
 public class LocationManager
{
    public async static Task<Geoposition> GetPosition()
    {
        var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (accessStatus != GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed) throw new Exception();

        var geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 0 };

        var position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

        return position;
    }
}
```

Downloading JSON code:

```
     private const string APPID = "f3c45b5a19426de9ea6ba7eb6c6969d7";
        public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(double lat, double lon)
            {
                var http = new HttpClient();
                var url = String.Format(
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={0}&lon={1}&units=metric&APPID="+APPID, lat, lon);
                var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

                var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
                var data = (RootObject) serializer.ReadObject(ms);

                return data;
            }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Coord
        {
            [DataMember]
            public double lon { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Weather
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int id { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string main { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string description { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string icon { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Main
        {
            [DataMember]
            public double temp { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double pressure { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double humidity { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double temp_min { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double temp_max { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Wind
        {
            [DataMember]
            public double speed { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double deg { get; set; }
        }

        /*
        [DataContract]
        public class Rain
        {
            [DataMember]
            public double __invalid_name__1h { get; set; }
        }
        */

        [DataContract]
        public class Clouds
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int all { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Sys
        {

            [DataMember]
            public int type { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public int id { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public double message { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string country { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public int sunrise { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public int sunset { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class RootObject
        {
            [DataMember]
            public Coord coord { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string @base { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public Main main { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public Wind wind { get; set; }

/*
                                                [DataMember]
                                                public Rain rain { get; set; }
                                                */

            [DataMember]
            public Clouds clouds { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public int dt { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public Sys sys { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public int id { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string name { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public int cod { get; set; }
        }
```

and there I show data like this:

```
 public async void WeatherDisplay()
    {
        try
        {
            //var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
            var geoLocator = new Geolocator();
            geoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            Geoposition pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            var lat = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
            var lon = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;

            RootObject myWeather =
                await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(
                    lat,
                    lon);



            Temperature.Text = ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + "°C";
           // DescriptionTextBlock.Text = myWeather.weather[0].description;
            City.Text = myWeather.name;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

My trouble in delays, I tap button and it show data in 30-40 seconds. With internet all okay. Why I have such big delays?

Comment: Hi, did you use fiddler or something simular to see what package size there is? If not I'd start there [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
If this isn't you problem I might think serializing takes to much time. I got good expirience with json.net [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) I'd try this out next.
If your package size is very big, you might want to think about using copression - there are very good 'fast' implementations for json.net aswell, If you need a link let me know.

Comment: And another suggestion: you functions are all async, but you use await, which will end making your method stop anyway. You might want to use a callback event when you async call is finished, so you can process the data when received.

Comment: @TripleEEE that's what `await` does.

Comment: @Eugene catch your packages with Fiddler (as stated above) to make some research. Also it's possible that  `api.openweather` is slow itself. And as a side note: do not create http client for each request, `HttpClient` (both in System.Net and UWP analogue) is meant to be instantiated once for the whole life of your application ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Hi Sergey, yeah I know that this is was await does, but I meant it different:
`private readonly Func<int> executionFunc = delegate() { return 1; };

    private Action<IAsyncResult> AsyncCallback = delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // DoStuff
    };

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        executionFunc.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(AsyncCallback), executionFunc);
    }`

Comment: @TripleEEE yeap, but I can't see how it should give any performance benefits over auto generated (over await-async pair) class that would have a method MoveNext() that will be called by callback function. Does classic "manual" async work faster then "syntactic sugar" of await-async?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov I wouldn't say it's faster in every case. But we don't know what other code could run after the `WeatherDisplay()` call. Maybe he even waits for the end of execution in the GUI Thread - what would freeze his app, or maybe there is some heavy calculation following. 
But in the end you are right - await async wont be faster or slower just by itself - depends on the whole architecture.

Comment: Hm, I launched app on PC. It takes 2 seconds to download data and display it. @TripleEEE

Comment: Will now try on Smartphone @TripleEEE

Comment: @Eugene 2 Seconds seem to be quite ok. Was it slower on your pc before? What did you change?

Comment: On Phone 28 seconds @TripleEEE